# Find Min and Abs Max with $\ln x$

Tags: calculus

I know how to do a quadratic version but how do  I find the absolute minimum and absolute maximum values of f on the given interval.
$f(x) = x − \ln 2x$,   $[\frac{1}{2}, 2]$

I keep getting the wrong answers

Comment: You do it **the exact same way** as [your previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/163153/742)! You find the critical points, you evaluate at the endpoints and at the critical points, and you compare the values. Remember that the critical points are the points where the derivative is either defined and equal to $0$, or undefined. As to "keep getting the wrong answers", if you bothered to show us what you did, perhaps we could tell you what you are doing wrong so you don't keep doing it.

Comment: Ah okay i thought there was something different to lnx questions. Thanks!

Comment: Why would you think that? Did you not cover finding extreme values in your course? The method does not depend on what goes into the function.

Comment: Im trying to learn calc on my own so im allover the place but im getting it slowly.

Comment: I am on the EVT today looking into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The derivative is $1-\frac{2}{2x}$. It is hard to go wrong after that. The contenders are $x=1/2$, $x=1$, and $x=2$.

Answer (score 1):

First you find the critical points of $f(x)$. That would be done by finding $f'(x)$ and setting that equal to 0. 
So $f'(x) = 0$, solve for $x$.

After checking the critical points, you must also check the boundaries, which are $\frac{1}{2}$ and $2$.

**EDIT:** Also, you have to find places where $f(x)$ is not differentiable to find all critical points.

Comment: Not quite accurate; your  method only finds the *stationary* points, not all the critical points

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you call the usual ones stationary critical points?

Comment: @MGNewman: A stationary point is a point where the derivative is zero (it comes from thinking about the derivative as representing speed... when the speed is $0$, you are stationary). Critical points are stationary points *and* points where the function is defined but not differentiable.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: The other critical points would be found where $f'(x)$ is not differentiable.

Comment: @Salazar: No, it doesn't matter where $f'(x)$ is not differentiable. It's the points where $f$ itself is not differentiable; so your description of how to find the critical points of $f$ is incomplete, as I noted.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: Just saw your comment. I kind of forgot about that. Thanks for raising the issue. I will add it to the response.